# Read json file content with require vs fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose that for every response from an API, i need to map the value from the response to an existing json file in my web application and display the value from the json. What are the better approach in this case to read the json file? require or fs.readfile. Note that there might be thousands of request comes in at a same time.

Note that I do not expect there is any changes to the file during runtime.

```
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
   // compare response identifier value with json file in node
   // if identifier value exist in the json file
   // return the corresponding value in json file instead
});
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I suppose you'll JSON.parse the json file for the comparison, in that case, `require` is better because it'll parse the file right away and it's sync:

```
var obj = require('./myjson'); // no need to add the .json extension
```

If you have thousands of request using that file, require it once outside your request handler and that's it:

```
var myObj = require('./myjson');
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
   // myObj is accessible here and is a nice JavaScript object
   var value = myObj.someValue;

   // compare response identifier value with json file in node
   // if identifier value exist in the json file
   // return the corresponding value in json file instead
});
```

Comment: Isn't `require` synchronous? Depending on the size of the JSON file or use case, fs.readFile should be better.

Comment: I too agree and even suggest, using piping for larger files. For the purpose of large connections, pigeon-holing (spatial / temporal indexing) of connections also prove to add great efficiency.

Comment: it's worth noting that `require` will cache the file, so if the content of that json file changes throughout the lifetime of the application, you won't see the updates

Comment: It's worth noting that due `require` caching when you mutate object you mutate it also for all future calls (so essentially it acts as an **singleton**). I had problem that I used same `require("test-payload.json")` in multiple tests cases and altered some properties on my way. In result one test case passed when ran in isolation but failed when ran with all other tests. So be aware of that and use spread operator to make object copy if needed.

Answer (score 57):

There are two versions for `fs.readFile`, and they are

Asynchronous version

```
require('fs').readFile('path/test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) 
       // error handling

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Synchronous version

```
var json = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('path/test.json', 'utf8'));
```

---

To use `require` to parse json file as below

```
var json = require('path/test.json');
```

But, note that

- `require` is synchronous and only reads the file once, following calls return the result from *cache*
- If your file does not have a `.json` extension, require will not treat the contents of the file as `JSON`.

Comment: I was wondering why my require('file.json') kept changing until I read this 
 - "require is synchronous and only reads the file once, following calls return the result from cache". This can be bypassed by - delete require.cache[require.resolve('file.json')]

Answer (score 16):

Since no one ever cared to write a benchmark, and I had a feeling that require works faster, I made one myself.

I compared fs.readFile (promisified version) vs require (without cache) vs fs.readFileSync.

You can see benchmark [here](https://github.com/jehy/node-fastest-json-read) and results [here](https://github.com/jehy/node-fastest-json-read/runs/416637981?check_suite_focus=true).

For 1000 iterations, it looks like this:

```
require: 835.308ms
readFileSync: 666.151ms
readFileAsync: 1178.361ms
```

So what should you use? The answer is not so simple.

1. Use require when you need to cache object forever. And better use Object.freeze to avoid mutating it in application.
2. Use readFileSync in unit tests or on blocking application startup - it is fastest.
3. Use readFile or promisified version when application is running and you don't wanna block event loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use [node-fixtures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fixtures) if dealing with JSON fixtures in your tests.

> The project will look for a directory named fixtures which must be child of your test directory in order to load all the fixtures (*.js or *.json files):

```
// test/fixtures/users.json
{
  "dearwish": {
    "name": "David",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  "innaro": {
    "name": "Inna",
    "gender": "female"
  }
}
```

```
// test/users.test.js
var fx = require('node-fixtures');
fx.users.dearwish.name; // => "David"
```

Answer (score 2):

I only want to point out that it seems `require` keeps the file in memory even when the variables should be deleted. I had following case:

```
for (const file of fs.readdirSync('dir/contains/jsons')) {
  // this variable should be deleted after each loop
  // but actually not, perhaps because of "require"
  // it leads to "heap out of memory" error
  const json = require('dir/contains/jsons/' + file);
}

for (const file of fs.readdirSync('dir/contains/jsons')) {
  // this one with "readFileSync" works well
  const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('dir/contains/jsons/' + file));
}
```

The first loop with `require` can't read all JSON files because of "heap out of memory" error. The second loop with `readFile` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "country": [    
    "INDIA",
    "USA"
  ],
  "codes": [   
    "IN",
    "US"
  ]
}

// countryInfo.json

const { country, code } = require('./countryInfo.json');

console.log(country[0]); // "INDIA"
console.log(code[0]); // "IN"
```

Comment: With object destructuring you could do `const { country, code } = require('countryInfo.json');`

Answer (score 1):

If your file is empty, require will break. It will throw an error:

> SyntaxError ... Unexpected end of JSON input.

With `readFileSync/readFile` you can deal with this:

```
let routesJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./routes.json', 'UTF8') || '{}');
```

or:

```
let routesJson
fs.readFile('./dueNfe_routes.json', 'UTF8', (err, data) => {
    routesJson = JSON.parse(data || '{}');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want complete ***control over exactly how late the JSON file is loaded*** into a JS object, try this.  I set this function to be triggered using window.onload, and after it started other things of greater importance.

```
function load_dictionary() { // called at end of window.onload func

    const NWL23_defs_script = document.createElement('script')

    NWL23_defs_script.src = `NWL23_defs.js?v=2024_01_02`

    NWL23_defs_script.setAttribute('defer', '') // defer further deprioritizes

    document.body.append(NWL23_defs_script)
}
```

Note that this will be cached if the server serves it with appropriate Cache-Control header, which is what I want, but you can easily override this with new query params, as illustrated.  And those params could be a JS var, too, like `[url]?v=${current_version}` which could then be updated by the server in any number of ways or by JS in a <script> tag in the HTML of your page (which isn't cached).

Here's my onload func, just to round out the do-it-last nature of this in my case:

```
window.onload = function window_onload() {

    [do other things which are more important]

    setTimeout(() => { // let's give it one more sec...
        load_dictionary()
    }, 1000)
}
```

Just in case it's not clear, the file loaded looks like so:

```
const NWL23_defs = {
    [I have ~200K key/value pairs, but you could have any JSON]
}
console.log("NWL23_defs loaded!")
```

My file is hosted on the Cloudflare CDN, is 5.9MB, but CF compresses it to 1.6MB -- and it just loaded with cache disabled in 605ms (with a crappy XFinity ISP service).  Happy late-as-you-want loading!