# Using node to dereference JSON schema

Tags: json, node.js

So I'm trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-deref) node package.  The usage instructions state that I need to `require` a JSON file. Something like this :

```
var myschema = require('schema.json');
```

But when I run this it wants to find a node package by the name of 'schema.json' and throws an error "Cannot find module 'schema.json'". How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Change it to `require('./schema.json');`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the libray you linked to is `json-schema-deref`

As such, to import that library you would do:

```
var deRefLib = require('json-schema-deref')
```

Then to load your schema file you'd need to use a require with a relative path.  If your schema is in the same directory as your JS file, you would use:

```
var mySchema = require('./schema.json')
```

Comment: Is it standard practice to `require` a JSON file instead of reading & `JSON.parse`ing it? I suppose there could be security implications.

Comment: What other means would you suggest to get your JSON string into your application to be `JSON.parse`d? 

 `require` statements are evaluated at the build/compilation stage of the application and as such, the developer has complete control over the code / files being executed.

Comment: Well, `fs.readFile[Sync]`. Is the "build/compilation stage" right when the application launches? You're referring to JIT compilation, right? And you can `require` a file at any time, am I wrong?

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I've too long been in the grunt/browserify world  :)

Re your original question in the context of a nodejs environment:  I'm not sure.   A quick google lead to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389060/read-json-file-content-with-require-vs-fs-readfile

Comment: Good link. Turns out there isn't a security issue; requiring a `.json` file parses it as JSON, not JS. The caching behavior and succinct syntax makes `require` clearly the better choice. [source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2908-you-can-use-require-to-load-json-javascript-object-notation-files-in-node-js.htm)