# I can't read a JSON file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hi I got the following code in Node.js

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    obj.data1.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log (element.key, element.key1);
    });
})
```

I am trying to show the key and the value of all the in the following json format:

```
{
    "data1": {
        "key": "iohiohio",
        "key1": "jhuihuj"
    },
    "data2": {
        "key4": "hoih",
        "key5": "kjhi"
   }
}
```

So i want the result to be like :

> key1:jhuihuj , key4: hoih

and be shown on a html/ejs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `obj` is returned from `fs.readFile` as a buffer or a string (if `utf-8` formatting is provided).

In order to convert the string or the buffer to an actual object You have to use `JSON.parse()` method.

Here is a commented code to understand what to do step by step:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./file.json",  "utf-8", function(err, obj) {
    // print your json file to the screen
    console.log(obj);

    // parse the obj string and convert it to an actual object
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

    // print the properties of obj.data1 as "key : value"
    for (k in obj.data1) {
        console.log(k, ":", obj.data1[k]);
    }
})
```

The console result:

```
D:\workspace\projects\node>node server
{
    "data1": {
        "key": "iohiohio",
        "key1": "jhuihuj"
    },
    "data2": {
        "key4": "hoih",
        "key5": "kjhi"
   }
}
key : iohiohio
key1 : jhuihuj
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133087/discussion-on-answer-by-abdelaziz-mokhnache-i-cant-read-a-json-file-with-node-j).

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of having your values inside an array? It's redundant because you have a single object in them. You could remove the square brackets and just have this:

```
{
    "data1": {
        "key": "iohiohio",
        "key1": "jhuihuj"
    },
    "data2": {
        "key4": "hoih",
        "key5": "kjhi"
    }
}
```

Then, you would loop it like this:

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    for (var k in obj.data1) {
        console.log(k + ": " + obj.data1[k]);
    }
});
```

That would print only the keys in `data1`, though! To print everything, you should use:

```
fs.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    try {
        obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error while parsing");
        return;
    }

    for (var k in obj) {
        for (var k2 in obj[k]) {
             console.log(k + " - " + k2 + ": " + obj[k][k2]);
        }
    }
});

// Result
// data1 - key: iohiohio
// data1 - key1: jhuihuj
// data2 - key4: hoih
// data2 - key5: kjhi
```

Edit: you should parse `obj`. It's also better to put it in a try catch block in case the JSON is wrong and couldn't be parsed.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389060/read-json-file-content-with-require-vs-fs-readfile), you could load the json with `require`:

```
var obj = require("./jsonfile");
for (var k in obj) {
    for (var k2 in obj[k]) {
         console.log(k + " - " + k2 + ": " + obj[k][k2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i get just this sir key1:jhuihuj

Comment: I don't see the line where you parse the file data, so I don't see how this would work. `fs.readFile` is supposed to return a Buffer object. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Hi @HristiyanDodov how do i print only 1? like key: iohiohio

Comment: Which one exactly? Tell me what is your goal? What do you want to achieve?