# JSON response in clientSide NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I want to get a .json file from server to .js file in ClientSide

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: '50mb'});
module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/tables_particular/', function(req, res){

    first = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database/table.json'))

    res.render('tables_particular', {todos: data.member, 
                                     tbledit: first,
                            });
});

app.post('/tables_particular/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){

    var exportlist = req.body.detail

    fs.writeFileSync('./database/table.json', exportlist); 
        res.json(exportlist);

});
```

and here is the app.js: (server code)

```
var express = require('express');

var mShController = require('./controllers/mShController');

var app = express();

//
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//static files
app.use(express.static('./public'));

mShController(app);


//listen to port
app.listen(3000);
console.log('You are listening to port 3000');
```

what is the code I need to use in javascript file to get the json file.

I need it in js file:

```
var data = response.tbledit
```

Comment: If `myfile.json` is static, you can just `const json = require('myfile.json')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var content;  
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('path/myfile.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;

    console.log(content); // HERE DO ANYTHING WITH THE JSON DATA
});
```

OR See this link [read-json-file-content-with-require-vs-fs-readfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389060/read-json-file-content-with-require-vs-fs-readfile)

```
var myObj = require('path/myfile');
var value = myObj.someValue;
});
```

Comment: but i don't need to change extension of file... i need to use the json file dynamically in javascript file to show it in a table

Comment: you have to add fs npm package.

Comment: use 'fs' package.

Comment: i use 'fs'.. but it work just in app.js (in server) not in Browser ( i mean : fs can't define in javascript file which work for html page).. i hope that i good explain

Comment: In Browser in response you can simple access it by using `response.tbledit'`because when you send json data from server to client then it didn't come as a file(it came as a JSON Data).

Comment: Like from my code var `myObj` is a JSON data not a json file so you can directly catch it like response.myObj

Comment: response is not defined... and the same when i use :    this.response.tbledit (tbledit not defined)

Comment: var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false, limit: '50mb'});

Comment: where is response defined ?? (show me clientside code where you will be parsing your response)