# I want to bring a single value from my json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This brings me all the values ​​of the json file

Example: I have id, name and lastname, I want to bring the id value

```
  fs.readFile("user.json", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

info file json

```
{"Identificador":0,"Nombre_Principal":"man","Nombre_Paterno":"man","Nombre_Materno":"man","Contrasena":"man","Correo":"man@man.com","Posicion":"User","Token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Im1hbiIsIm5iZiI6MTU0MjgzODU5OCwiZXhwIjoxNTQyODQwMzk4LCJpYXQiOjE1NDI4Mzg1OTgsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NjUyMjQiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjY1MjI0In0.W9Tck4QjzCoP2g0CdFIsmshSUoZbzi8AmzR9EnRYIVQ","Estatus":0}
```

Comment: Use JSON.parse() then access what you need as you would with any JavaScript object

Comment: I could do visual, please

Comment: @Brad What are you talking about? What was given is fine. An actual JSON file is not needed to answer this question.

Comment: sorry, I did not notice that I put jquery by mistake

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The whole question is how to access properties of an object.  Seeing an actual structure is helpful.

Comment: I have more, but the only thing I use to call the json is what I wrote above

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez This is sufficient, thanks for updating your question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read json file content with require vs fs.readFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389060/read-json-file-content-with-require-vs-fs-readfile)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This question appears to be for Node.js (see the updated tags), and isn't quite a duplicate of what you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can access the actual data inside the string containing JSON, you have to parse it first.  Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for this.

```
fs.readFile('user.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data = JSON.parse(data);  // Convert JSON into an actual JavaScript object
  console.log(data.Identificador); // Access object properties with the dot `.` notation
});
```